# calculate percentage within condition

Tags: r, percentage

[This output is not what I want because the 'lbl' column generates the percentages by dividing n/(sum(n)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnL0f.png)
[This output would be what I expect in that the percentages are calculated by 'Response' within 'Condition'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGV9X.png)

The following codes I used always generate the wrong output. Does anyone have any idea as to how to fix this problem? Your help is much appreciated!

```
UN_sent %>%
  group_by(Condition, Response, .groups='keep') %>%
  dplyr::summarize(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n),
         lbl = scales::percent(pct))
```

Comment: please check `UN_sent %>%
  group_by(Condition, Response) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n),
         lbl = scales::percent(pct)) %>%
  ungroup()`